# Determining the sum of a series as a function of the variable x

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{9n}}{n!}
$$
I want to find the sum of the series of as a function of $x$.

It seems to resemble the Taylor series where of  $e^x$ which is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

I have also considered it as a telescoping series (which is not) and a geometric series ( which also does not seem to be the case).

How should I approach this problem ?

[image: questionathand]

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, this sum resembles the Taylor series of $e^{x}$, which is
$$e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
After thinking about this a bit, we see that 
$$e^{-x^{9}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^{9})^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{9n}}{n!}$$